# Plot the mean values of pixels on a single graph

Tags: numpy

I have a series of images (each 2 seconds a new image is taken) and want to calculate the mean pixel brightness for each image.

How can I plot the means on a single graphic, so that I have the evolution of the mean?

Below is the simple code I wrote to retrieve the mean values.

```py
data = glob.glob ("D:/Documents/597/04/*.png")
data.sort()
    
for i in range (0, len(data)):
    img = cv.imread(data[i])
    if img is not None:
        img = np.array(img[:, :, 0])
        mean = format(img.mean())
        print(mean)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "mean pixel brightness"? Sort of a grayscale image, or the average brightness of each image?

Comment: What I meant is that I want the sum of the pixel values divided by the total value. As in a regular mean.

Answer (score 1):

Stack the images in one common array and do the mean in one go:

```py
files = sorted(glob.glob("D:/Documents/597/04/*.png"))
imgs = [cv.imread(f) for f in files]     # list of 67 color images with 256x256 pixels each
imgs = np.array(imgs)                    # array of shape 67x256x256x3
plt.plot(imgs.mean(axis=(1, 2, 3))       # array of shape 67
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it out and it is exactly what I wanted. Is there any tutorial you would recommend to learn more regarding visualization? I want to do the same with the center of mass and zernike moments. I have the code written in the same style as the question above. I am struggling with the visualization, and figuring out what I need to do. Thank you in advance